# cohomology algebra of submanifold in euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, na.numerical-analysis, cohomology, computer-science, approximation-theory

If we write a manifold or CW-complex $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in expression of coordinates, for example, \begin{multline}
F(S^2,k+1)=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_{3k+1},x_{3k+2},x_{3k+3})\in\mathbb{R}^{3k+3}\\ \mid 
  x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1,\cdots, x_{3k+1}^2+x_{3k+2}^2+x_{3k+3}^2=1,\\
  \text{ for }i\neq j, x_{3i+1}\neq x_{3j+1} \text{ or } x_{3i+2}\neq x_{3j+2} \text{ or }x_{3i+3}\neq x_{3j+3} \},
\end{multline}
is there any computer software or programming that can give the cohomology algebra automatically?

Can the computer give a very complicated simplicial complexes to approximate the manifold and compute the cohomology algebra?

Comment: This is not explicit in the question, perhaps on purpose, but the very specific space $F(S^2,k+1)$ is also known as the configuration space of $k+1$ points on $S^2$. Googling around shows that there supposedly already is a way ([Totaro 1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(95)00058-5)) to compute the rational cohomology algebra of this space using spectral sequence methods. I guess the thrust of the question is whether an automated approach to this computation (if one is possible) would be advantageous to this alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely depends on what expressions you want to allow, 
but what comes to my mind is that even the much more basic question whether 
a given set is empty or not

- is NP-complete, so don't expect an effective algorithm,
- is computable by Tarski's theorem.

Maybe a logician could say more.